# How to hide/ Remove action columns Item?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch

I have a problem for hide/remove action column Item on record condition in grid view.
let see bellow code. there is action column code I did. I want to hide delete Icon shown in image. this delete icon hide/remove on record condition.

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    flex: 1,
    align: 'center',
    scope: this,
    renderer: function (n, t, rec) {
        /*  if (rec.get('companyId') == 23) {
            console.log('Distributor Account List');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Distributor Client user List');
        } */
    },
    items: [
        {
            icon: FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/edit2.png',
            tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERLIST_EDIT_'),
            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                this.fireEvent('showUserDetails', rec);
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'spacer'
        },
        {
            icon: (Ext.getStore('userStore').first().get('issuperadmin') == 1 || Ext.getStore('userStore').first().get('isadmin') == 1 || Ext.getStore('userStore').first().get('isadmin') == 3) ?
            FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/vehicles/van-icon.png' : '',  // Use a URL in the icon config
            tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERLIST_VEHICLE_'),
            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                this.fireEvent('assignvehicles', rec);
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'spacer'
        },
        {
            icon: FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/del.png',
            tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERLIST_DELETE_'),
            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                Me = this;
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERLIST_REMOVETITLE_'),
                    msg: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERLIST_REMOVEMSG_'),
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                    icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                    callback: function (button) {
                        if (button == fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_USER_USERLIST_YESBTN_')) {
                            Me.removeUser(rec);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

There are 4 items in action column (Edit icon, spacer, spacer, and delete Icon) please see Attached image.
[image]

In above code there is Action column render event. e.g. I want to check record having company ID=23. I use this condition for testing. Main problem is that I want to hide that delete Icon on condition. Any proper solution for this?

Comment: is it jquery data table ?
if no please let us see the whole javascript code

Comment: Its a ExJs(sencha) Grid View.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that i dont have experience with it

Comment: Not totally related to your question, but if you are considering disabling the action items instead of hiding, there is an [isDisabled](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-isDisabled) method available for action items that might come in handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not use the `icon` property, but you want to put the icons into the corresponding CSS in a class. E.g.

```
.someIcon {
     background-image: path/to/icon.png no-repeat center center !important;
     width:20px;
     height:20px;
}
```

and then you can add a [`getClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-getClass) config instead of the icon config, and provide the CSS classes as needed, e.g. if you want to switch icon on or off:

```
getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {
    if(rec.get('companyId')==23) return 'someIcon';
    else return '';
}
```

or, if you want to have different icons, e.g.:

```
getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {
    if(rec.get('isImportant')) return 'redIcon';
    else return 'greyIcon';
}
```

Please note that you have to recompile your project in Sencha Cmd if you add classes through SCSS.